# Migrate Bugnet to JIRA

Tags: sql-server, jira

I want to migrate/transfer an existing Bugnet installation to JIRA.

As there are many projects and issues, I want to do this automatically.

The .csv export and JIRA-CSV-Import is not enough.

The .csv-export lacks of comments and descriptions.

Any ideas how to solve this? Directly in SQL?